# imregtform giving "Registration failed because optimization diverged." error in matlab

Tags: matlab, alignment

I am trying to align an atlas on a brain section via shape similarity. I converted both images  to grayscale and filled them in white like so:

Section:

[image: Section]

Atlas:

[image: Atlas]

I tried aligning them by similarity using imregtform. However I get the error "Registration failed because optimization diverged." Is there a value in the optimizer that needs to be changed?

Or is there an easier way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

I do not actually have the Image Processing Toolbox, but you should take a look at some of the help files.  For instance, Mathworks has many sections online discussing how you can do image processing, including alignment.  This link is somewhat a top level discussion (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html#spatial-transformation-and-image-registration) and this seems like it might be a great tool for you to do image alignment using the control point alignment technique (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/point-mapping.html).

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.  With out having the toolbox, I can't try the suggested tools.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, Matlabs image registration only offers linear (geometric) transformations atm. That is, only translation, rotation, scale, and shear is allowed. This is not enough for your images since you have local distortions.

What you need is a non-rigid (elastic) registration. You can find some codes for this in the file-exchange.